# How to handle n requests in multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Programming,In my company we have Booking System.For our Software I will get a XML request to our service. when ever we get an request to our service. we create a thread and process it.This software works fine.But recently we got new problem.One of our client is sending his booking information(10000 XML's for example) at X hour(for example 1:AM) every Day.As our Software behaves we are creating 10000 Threads. Then we are Getting OutOfMemorryError.To improve this we are thinking to implement with Executors.
My Question is are we using the Best way to handle 10000 requests ?
Any Suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably ask one of your senior devs....

Comment: I'd suggest using java.nio, where you can use a set of threads to service a large number of connections.  Can also look into netty, which is an implementation of nio using a pipelining model.

Comment: @redFIVE I agree. However, if they knew the solution, such architecture would never be created in the first place. And it's a bit worrying that none of the senior devs knows about thread pools...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Executor` which has a maximum number of threads, e.g.:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor
    = new ThreadPoolExecutor(50, 50, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
executor.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
```

First 50 is `corePoolSize`, second 50 is `maximumPoolSize`. The difference is that more than `corePoolSize` threads will be created only if the queue is full.

We don't want to have 50 idle threads so we let them timeout (`allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true)`) after 60 seconds.

You may also want to set maximum capacity on the queue. If all threads are busy and queue is full, the exception will be thrown (rather than `OutOfMemoryError` when you attempt to add too much to the queue).

Then you just call `executor.submit(...)` and give it `Runnable` or `Callable` as a parameter.